# PMSM failure modes? Winding apparently not shorted

Tags: synchronous-motor, pmsm

(This may look like a repair question, but I'm actually interested in *how* the simplest kind of motor failed)

This is the stator of a permanent-magnet single-phase motor from a washing machine drain pump:

[image: PMSM stator]

There's two coils in series with a [thermal interrupter](https://www.sensata.com/sites/default/files/a/sensata-3mp-motor%20protector-datasheet.pdf), and a permanent-magnet rotor goes in the gap. That's all.

The rotor spins with force (I can't stop it with my fingers) but *irregularly*, especially in the first few seconds after applying power:

https://i.imgur.com/137FDoU.mp4

Conventional wisdom says the windings are shorted, so I measured R≈12Ω, ~6Ω each half (it's rated 85W@120V; I don't know of a rule of thumb to estimate the number of turns). In case both halves had similar partial shorts, I unwound one down to the bobbin and didn't find stuck turns or visibly bare copper. The rotor turns smoothly, snapping magnetically every 180°. Shorting the thermal interrupter doesn't change anything.

So, how else can this simple device fail to turn evenly?

Comment: Have you checked the bearings/bushings for whether they turn smoothly? I watched your video and wondered if it is rattling and jamming up mechanically.

Comment: Yup, I mentioned that the rotor turns smoothly though you can feel the magnet snapping to the stator every half-turn. It's not a mechanical issue. The rattling comes from the uneven velocity.

Comment: You mention that you removed one of the windings. If you didn't already, you should just confirm that the resistance is 12 Ohms when it is all stretched out. I don't know what else could be wrong. Permanent magnet overheat and de-magnetized? Did the winding core fail somehow so that it is developing eddy currents?

Comment: "I'm actually interested in how the simplest kind of motor failed" - it failed in the washing machine? What were the symptoms?

Comment: @mkeith, I *think* I measured again while it was loose, but anyway when I wound it back in a slightly different way the short should've been removed, no? I'm curious about the insulation between laminations.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Didn't pump water out (I had to lay the hose down to drain the tub by gravity). Removing the hose I could see it turning oddly.

Comment: I didn't realize you rewound it. I agree most likely  short is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into a similar problem, and from my research, a countertorque of precisely the correct magnitude is required for this type of motor to start successfully and reliably.

See this patent: https://patents.google.com/patent/EP1428926A2/en
The patent is for a mechanism that allows this to happen. I suspect that if you pull out the rotor of your motor (it is held in magnetically but should come out with a good tug), you'll see (or feel) a similar mechanism.

You probably aren't seeing correct starting behavior since the motor is designed to be started when submerged underwater.

Comment: You're right - I installed it and it starts fine when the tub has water. IIRC I pulled out the rotor and there's no flywheel inside.